# Achieving good drawing refresh rate in Forms

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface

I am trying to draw in a form which is receiving input asynchronously from another thread.  The input process consumes a large amount of CPU time.  I therefore am trying to set a refresh rate for something around 10 times per second, but am struggling to achieve even that.  I am wondering what you guys think I can do to speed up my code, if anything?  I've tried to reduce it to the simplest amount of code here.  Some code was originally copied from a different application found on the web, so I apologize if I've left something extraneous (feel free to tell me).  I can try to provide more code from abstracted methods on request.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TagReader;
using Interactor;
using MathNet.Numerics.Distributions;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Media;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RFIDInteraction
{
    abstract class RFIDApplication : Form
    {


        DateTime lastTime = DateTime.Now;
        int refreshEllapse = (int)1000 / 10; //only refresh if 10 ms have passed

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;


        protected void maybeRefresh()
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - lastTime).Milliseconds > refreshEllapse)
            {
                this.Refresh();
                lastTime = DateTime.Now;
            }



        }



        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        private void InputWrapper(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            updateLoopStep(inputs); //code in this method (not shown) does some update based on the input - this could be expensive


            maybeRefresh();
        }



        #region boringstuff
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.SuspendLayout();

            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 1000);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.Name = "Application";
            this.Text = "Application";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.LoadContent);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        protected Application()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler inputCallback =
                new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(InputWrapper);



            new TagStatesThread(inputCallback); //Thread runs in background - could be an expensive process

        }


        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }


        protected void LoadContent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.SetStyle(
                ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer,
                true);
            this.UpdateStyles();

            loadAllContent(); //some simple method (not shown) which loads Image assets and such (once)

        }


        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);

            //code in this method (not shown) handles drawing all the Images - by simply iterating through them all and calling e.Graphics.DrawImage.  May have to draw a large number of images (up to 100)
           displayNewState(e.Graphics);


        }





    }
}
```

Also, a question - when a call to draw is made, and nothing has to be done, it seems to draw much faster - implying that if a pixel does not have to be changed, it consumes almost negligible processing time (suggesting the system automatically checks what needs to be drawn and is pretty intelligent).  Is this true?

Edit: Screenshot of an example application:

[image: TicTacToeBoard]

Comment: If this is for a game, maybe consider using a specialized framework. You can get much better updating speed because it will be optimized for that.

Comment: You're not providing  enough detail. What are you  trying to "draw"?  what does your form contain? can you provide a screenshot? what are these images? are you reading them from disk?

Comment: Kailanjian - If you can recommend a good one, I am willing to use it.  HighCore - I am trying to do a visualization for prallel TicTacToe games; I need to draw the X/O sprites many times each.  Images are loaded once from disk at the start of the game.  I'm providing a screenshot.  The draw command iterates for each game and draws a transparent X at the appropriate coordinate.

Comment: FYI, I created a  rough mockup of your app in WPF, put 200 tic tac toe boards of 3x3 each, randomly changing squares every 10 ms using a Timer, and I get no lag at all. Forget winforms, its completely useless. Let me know if you're interested and I'll post the code.

Comment: I would be extremely interested.

Answer (score 2):

Alright so, this is how you'd do  that in WPF:

### Step 1:

Create a small **Data Model** that will represent your Tic Tac Toe Games with their squares:

```
public enum SquareValue
{
    Empty = 0,
    X = 1,
    O = 2
}

public class Square: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SquareValue _value;
    public SquareValue Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Game
{
    public List<Square> Squares { get; private set; }

    public Game()
    {
        this.Squares = 
            Enumerable.Range(0, 9)
                      .Select(x => new Square { Value = SquareValue.Empty })
                      .ToList();
    }
}
```

> Notice that the Square class needs to [Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41817/Implementing-INotifyPropertyChanged) in order to support two-way DataBinding.

### Step 2:

Using an [ItemsControl](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/), define how each Tic Tac Toe board is going to look like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Squares}" Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkBlue">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray"  BorderThickness="1">
                <Path x:Name="Path" Stretch="Fill"
                      Margin="2"/>
            </Border>

            <!-- to be continued... -->
```

> Notice that we set the [`ItemsPanel`](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/02/10/itemscontrol-p-is-for-panel/) to a 3x3 [`UniformGrid`](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/uniformgrid/), and that the [`ItemTemplate`](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/01/03/itemscontrol-d-is-for-datatemplate/) contains an empty [`Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms747393(v=vs.100).aspx).

### Step 3:

Using [`DataTrigger`](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/522041/Triggers-in-WPF)s, we define how the square will look like depending on whether it's `Empty`, `X`, or `O`:

```
            <!-- continuation of the above XAML -->
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="X">
                    <Setter TargetName="Path" Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Path" Property="Data" Value="M0,0 L10,10 M0,10 L10,0"/>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="O">
                    <Setter TargetName="Path" Property="Stroke" Value="Blue"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Path" Property="Data">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Center="0.0,0.0"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

### Step 4:

We now have the XAML for each Tic Tac Toe board, let's now create some XAML to represent *many* boards, again, using another `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="10" Columns="10"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- the above XAML for a single Tic Tac Toe board goes here -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

> Notice that this time we're using a 10 x 10 `UniformGrid` because we will show 100 Tic Tac Toe boards

### Step 5:

Now we set our Window's [`DataContext`](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) to a list of our Game class:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
        {
            this.DataContext = Enumerable.Range(0,100)
                                         .Select(x => new Game())
                                         .ToList();
        };
    }
}
```

### Step 6:

Using whatever method you desire, modify the `Value` property of the `Square`s so that they become `X`, or `O`. In this case since this is just a demo I'll use a `Timer` and set it randomly. Modify the `Game` class like so:

```
public class Game
{
    public List<Square> Squares { get; private set; }
    private Timer timer;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public Game()
    {
        this.Squares = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(x => new Square {Value = SquareValue.Empty}).ToList();
        this.timer = new Timer(Callback, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
    }

    private void Callback(object state)
    {
        var sq = Squares[random.Next(0, 9)];
        var value = random.Next(0, 3);
        sq.Value = (SquareValue) value;
    }
}
```

## Result:

[image]

- Rendering is immediate and there's absolutely no lag
- UI is resolution independent and adjusts to the window size. You can try running this project and resizing the window to see how smooth it is.
- The Data Model is completely decoupled from the UI and the UI does not need any sort of code behind hacks. It's just *Simple, Simple Properties and DataBinding.*
- You can further customize the boards, Xs and Os to look however you want. WPF uses vector graphics which can be infinitely stretched without losing quality.
- Total code in this sample is 25 lines of C# + some 40 lines of XAML. Much less than it would require to do something similar in winforms, and yet the result is much better.
- Full source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/High-Core/WPFSamples/tree/master/MultiTicTacToe).
- Forget winforms.

Comment: Okay, wow, this is awesome and very impressive.  On the other hand, this would/will also require some nontrivial refactoring.  So I'm going to upvote this, and hopefully try this sometime in the following week, but I'm going to leave the question open to see if there are any other simpler / lightweight suggestions.  I'm definitely using WPF at some point in the near future, though :-)